# Unwrapping a type in typescript

Tags: typescript

I have a property of type `IDictionary<string>` where a dictionary is defined as:

```
export interface IDictionary<T = any> {
  [key: string]: T;
}
```

I would like to define a method which constrains the type to "string" in this case. Basically it unwraps the dictionary and exposes the type of it's values. Now, in matter of fact, there is another layer of abstraction involved here. So specifically my method is defined as:

```
 public async pushKey<K extends keyof T, KK extends keyof K>(property: K, value: K[KK]) { ... }
```

So here, the type `T` is defined at the class level and is a set of properties which may be a "push key". This method is intended for those properties which *are* a "pushKey" and would therefore also be a object with string key's and values which could be constrained as any data structure. For simplicity sake we could assume it is always the `IDictionary<string>` structure as that is clearly a valid use case.

I would have thought that the above signature would have gotten me what I was looking for but for a property T[K] -- which is indeed a `IDictionary<string>` -- I get the following type info from vs-code:

[image]

Can anyone help?

Comment: So in your example value should be of type `string` ? And if you had a `IDictionary<number>` it should be `number` ?

Comment: yes that is right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the type query for `KK` indexes into `K` which is a `string`, so the type of `value` will always be a union of all properties of `string`. Based on your description, you want `KK` to be a key of the type of the property `T[K]`

```
class dd<T> {

    public async pushKey<K extends keyof T, KK extends keyof T[K]>(property: K, value: T[K][KK]) { ... }
}

declare let d:dd<{
    prop: IDictionary<string>
}>;

d.pushKey("prop", "dd") // ok
d.pushKey("prop", 1) //error, not a value for prop
```

Although since you don't actually use `KK` in any other sort of capacity it will never get constrained to anything more specific then `keyof T[K]`, so you could achieve the same effect without `KK`:

```
public async pushKey<K extends keyof T>(property: K, value: T[K][keyof T[K]]) { ... }
```